# problems inserting to sql table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a website I'm developing, and when a user creates an account I want to store some additional info i have collected during the CreateUserWizard.  When I run the code, i get an error when trying to write the data to a table I have created.  I created the table in the ASPNETDB.mdf database (the one created by default) called UserProfile and has all the columns I'm trying to write to.  In the web.config file I have:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When the user creates an account, here is the code I have in the Creating_User event.

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
            string trimUserName = RegisterUser.UserName.Trim();
            if (RegisterUser.UserName.Length != trimUserName.Length)
            {
                accountlbl.Text = "The username cannot contain leading or trailing spaces.";
                accountlbl.Visible = true;
                //Cancel the created user info
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            if (RegisterUser.Password.IndexOf(RegisterUser.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            {
                accountlbl.Text = "The username may not appear anywhere in the password.";
                accountlbl.Visible = true;
                //Cancel the created user info
                e.Cancel = true;
            }


            String FirstName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName")).Text;
            String LastName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName")).Text;
            String Company = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("CompanyName")).Text;
            String PartsList = ((DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("companyddl")).SelectedValue;
            String UserName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
            String Password = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).Text;
            String Email = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email")).Text;
            String Question = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Question")).Text;
            String Answer = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Answer")).Text;
            // Insert a new record into User_Profile            
            if ((Company == "OurCompany" || Company == "OurCompany, Inc.") && PartsList == "")
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "manager");
                UserRole = "manager";
            }
            if (PartsList == "SF")
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "user_sf");
                UserRole = "user_sf";
            }
            if (PartsList == "TL")
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "user_tl");
                UserRole = "user_tl";
            }
            if ((Company != "OurCompany" || Company != "OurCompany, Inc.") && PartsList == "")
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "user");
                UserRole = "user";
            }

            // Get your Connection String from the web.config. ApplicationServices is the name I have in my web.config
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
            string insertSql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile(FirstName, LastName, Company, PartsList, UserName, Password, Email, Question, Answer, UserRole)" +
                               "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Company, @Partslist, @UserName, @Password, @Email, @Question, @Answer, @UserRole)";
            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", Company);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartsList", PartsList);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", Question);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", Answer);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", UserRole);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  //ERROR HERE!!!//
                myConnection.Close();                    
            }
    }
```

I get an error on the myComman.ExecuteNonQuery(); statement saying -- Must declare the scalar variable "@UserRole".
If I comment out the code, it will not write anything to the database table.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", UserRole);`, but I think you should have `myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserRole", UserRole);`.

Comment: Gotta love working on something so long you don't see the obvious...Thanks!  now I'm getting an error -- The parameterized query '(@FirstName nvarchar(6),@LastName nvarchar(9),@Company nvarchar(' expects the parameter '@UserRole', which was not supplied.
do I need to add something like:
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, FirstName);
where the SqlDbType matches the actual datatype in the database?

Comment: Does `UserRole` contain a value or is it null? If null value is allowed, put `DBNull.Value` in as a parameter value.

Comment: UserRole should have a value assigned to if previously in the code.  And in the database table, null value is not allowed.

Comment: Are you sure the parameter is properly set? You should debug it and/or dump all the parameters before the command is executed. I think there are conditions under which the `UserRole` can contain null value.

Comment: Well one thing I just noticed was in my table the last column is "Role" and I was trying to assign a "UserRole", however I still get an error with the same message.  How would I check the params and dump them all before executing the command?

Comment: Alright, using the debugger I finally figured it out.  Looks like now I'm having an email issue when the user is created but that should be easy to get resolved.  Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Just for any future info if anyone else comes across the wierd email error...I got an error that said:
**Syntax error, command unrecognized.  The server response was:  5.4.1  MUST COMPLETE IMAGE PUZZLE BEFORE SENDING, PLEASE GO TO** http://challenge.aol.com/spam.html
There was a problem with my internet browser that would crash everytime I tried to login to my aol email account.  I just restarted my computer and then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who cares...here's the working code:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatingUser(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
    {
            string trimUserName = RegisterUser.UserName.Trim();
            if (RegisterUser.UserName.Length != trimUserName.Length)
            {
                accountlbl.Text = "The username cannot contain leading or trailing spaces.";
                accountlbl.Visible = true;
                //Cancel the created user info
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            if (RegisterUser.Password.IndexOf(RegisterUser.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
            {
                accountlbl.Text = "The username may not appear anywhere in the password.";
                accountlbl.Visible = true;
                //Cancel the created user info
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            String FirstName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("FirstName")).Text;
            String LastName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("LastName")).Text;
            String Company = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("CompanyName")).Text;
            String PartsList = ((DropDownList)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("companyddl")).SelectedValue;
            String UserName = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("UserName")).Text;
            String Password = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Password")).Text;
            String Email = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Email")).Text;
            String Question = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Question")).Text;
            String Answer = ((TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Answer")).Text;
            // Insert a new record into User_Profile            
            if (((Company == "OurCompany" || Company == "OurCompany, Inc.") && PartsList == ""))
            {
                if (!User.IsInRole("manager"))
                {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "manager");
                Role = "manager";
                }
            }
            if (PartsList == "SF")
            {
                if (!User.IsInRole("user_sf"))
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "user_sf");
                    Role = "user_sf";
                }
            }
            if (PartsList == "TL")
            {
                if (!User.IsInRole("user_tl"))
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "user_tl");
                    Role = "user_tl";
                }
            }
            if ((Company != "OurCompany" || Company != "OurCompany, Inc.") && PartsList == "")
            {
                if (!User.IsInRole("user"))
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "user");
                    Role = "user";
                }
            }

            ////Get your Connection String from the web.config...ApplicationServices is the name I have in my web.config
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
            string insertSql = "INSERT INTO UserProfile(FirstName, LastName, Company, PartsList, UserName, Password, Email, Question, Answer, Role)" +
                               "VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Company, @Partslist, @UserName, @Password, @Email, @Question, @Answer, @Role)";

            using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", Company);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartsList", PartsList);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", Question);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Answer", Answer);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", Role);

                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();                    
            }
    }
```